# Tally Up Number of Occurrences in Angular

Tags: html, angularjs

So basically I have this quiz app im working on using angular and I want to tally up the amount of times the right answer is entered. I already made it so the words 'CORRECT' are displayed by the question if they type the right answer in the text box, but I want to see how many times that happens. Here is my code

```
div ng-repeat="q in questions">
    <span>{{ q.question }}</span><br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="q.ans"  name="email" placeholder="">  

    <div ng-show="q.ans===q.answer">CORRECT!</div>

<div>
```

so basically questions is just an array with a question string and answer string. I want to see at the end how many are correct. So I'm thinking, I added in a correct property to the question objects that has a default of 0 which could mean wrong, and change when its right to 1.

Now how would I make it change from the html page here when someone types the right answer? like if correct is shown, if the ng-show is right, then that value would be 1, if not, it'd be 0.

thanks for any assistance. Wondering if I could do this in real time instead of having a 'check' button at the end.

EDIT: okay I looking around the ng-if directive, would it somehow be possible to add like

```
<div ng-if="q.ans===q.answer">{{ q.correct = 1 }} </div>
```

or somehow execute that q.correct = 1 (meaning that answer is correct) if the ng-if block is run?

Answer (score 1):

[Make a filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters) for counting the correct answers

```
// app is your module
app.filter('correctCount', function() {
    return function(questions) {
        return questions.reduce(function(count, q) {
            return count + (q.ans === q.answer ? 1 : 0);
        }, 0);
    };
})
```

Then you can display the total in your template

```
Total: {{questions | correctCount | number}}
```

Demo ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/br3fxHQ8q04ajZj6Fxch?p=preview

---

An alternative to `reduce` that might be easier to understand is...

```
return questions.filter(function(q) {
    return q.ans === q.answer;
}).length;
```

Comment: thats actually perfect thanks so much. im still going through it logically tryin g to figure out how it works. the reduce function just executes the callback as a parameter?

Comment: @crooked91 here's the doco for `reduce` ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: quick question, how come if I change q.ans to just ans in the model and in teh filter, it wouldnt work anymore (instead it just shows the filter | angular code

Comment: Because just `ans` isn't defined anywhere